# Image in DataTemplate from Url\Device

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have this `DataTemplate` in my `ListBox`:

```
<local:SearchTemplateSelector.VideoTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
      <Rectangle Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="Black" Opacity="0.3" />
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{Binding Path=ImgUrl}" Width="100" Height="100" />
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,8,0">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,-5,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text="Views:  " FontSize="20" Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewCount}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black"/>
          </StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeStr}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</local:SearchTemplateSelector.VideoTemplate>
```

Now i have Image that i binding from ImgUrl of my object.And i want to know if there is possibility to make something like this:
If the image is in the device take it from the device,if not download it and save it on the device for next time, every image have a unique id so i can just save it with `id.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you have to add logic to `ImgUrl` property. You have to add some method in `Set{}`, which will `try` load image from `isolatedStorage`, and `catch` exception, in which it will use method to load and save image to `isolatedStorage`.